# How to integrate Jedi's help files with Delphi's IDE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, jedi

There are a lot of [help files at SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jvcl/files/JVCL%20Help%20Files/) for Jedi but none in the HxS format.

Is there a way to integrate it into Delphi's help system? I'm using Delphi 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi7Help4BDS might be of some use for this:
 http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphi7help4bds/